# Using LibXML to filter one XML based on another XML in Perl

Tags: xml, algorithm, perl, filter, libxml2

I'm having some difficulty coming up with an algorithm that will read in my filter.xml and then remove all message nodes from my log.xml. I've tried to start with a small case of one filter instead of shooting for multiple filters at once, but the idea is that a message must match all the elements in the filter to be removed.

Here is an example of a filter.xml that would remove all warning messages that contain the string "hurts really bad":

```
<filter>
  <type>warning</type>
  <content>hurts really bad</content>
</filter>
```

And here is an example of the log.xml with 2 different warning messages:

```
<log>
  <message>
    <type>warning</type>
    <from>cody</from>
    <content>my head hurts really bad right now</content>
  </message>
  <message>
    <type>error</type>
    <from>cody</from>
    <content>i've got too many nested for loops</content>
  </message>
  <message>
    <type>warning</type>
    <from>charlie</from>
    <content>ruff</content>
  </message>
</log>
```

I have no trouble loading the files in with LibXML, but when I try to come up with the algorithm to begin comparing the filters to the messages, I just end up with for loops within for loops until I realize what I am trying will not work, usually due to removing all warnings before checking for the content string. Anyone have any pseudocode ideas on how to accomplish this? I want the output to have the first warning message removed from the original log.xml due to it matching BOTH the type and containing the content string from the filter.xml. That means only the error and the second warning message will be the only 2 items in the new log.xml. I know how to overwrite the xml as well as compare the strings using index. Just need to get this algorithm knocked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I finally solved it. This sub will remove any items found in the filter.xml

```
sub exclude {
  my $filterParser = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($filterXML);
  my $logParser = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($xml);

  my $remove = false;   

  foreach my $filter ( $filterParser->findnodes('/filters/filter') ) {
    foreach my $msg ( $logParser->findnodes('/log/message') ) {
        foreach my $msgNode ($msg->childNodes) {
            foreach my $filterNode ($filter->childNodes) {
                if ($msgNode->localName eq $filterNode->localName) {
                    my $m = $msgNode->textContent;
                    my $f = $filterNode->textContent;
                    if (index($m, $f) != -1) {
                        $remove = true;
                    }
                    else { $remove = false; }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($remove eq true) {
            $msg->parentNode->removeChild($msg);
            $remove = false;
        }
    }
  }
  $logParser->toFile($xml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you build a hash of arrays from your filter XML that has the type as keys and an array of all the contents for that type as values. Like this

```
my %filters = (
  warning => [
    'hurts really bad',
    'content 2',
    'content 3',
    ...
  ],
);
```

Then you're done with the `filter.xml` data file.

Now, as you encounter each `<message>` element in the `log.xml` file, you should

- Check whether there is an element of `%filters` for the message's type
- If not then the test fails, i.e. the message isn't filtered
- If so then check each string in the array referenced by the element's value to see if it's a substring of the current message's content
- If no such string is found then the test fails, i.e. the message isn't filtered
- Otherwise the test is successful, and the message is filtered out

Assuming you're using a regex to check whether the filters match the content, don't forget to escape (with `quotemeta`) any regex met a characters in the *content* strings. Also, you may want to convert each hash value into a compiled regex to make the check simpler. That is, change it from the above structure to

```
my %filters = (
  warning => qr/hurts really bad|content 2|content 3|.../,
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to solve with just using for loops. Your way may be much better than my way, but it seemed quite complicated at first, so I opted to keep trying with for loops until I was successful.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot more straighforward if you read the filter data into memory as I suggested. Then all you have to do is to look at each `<message>` element in the log and remove it if it matches any of the criteria.

Here's how it looks

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use List::Util 'any';

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new(no_blanks => 1);

my $filters = $parser->load_xml(location => 'filter.xml');

my %filters;

for my $filter ( $filters ->findnodes('/filters/filter') ) {
  my $type = $filter->findvalue('type');
  my $content = $filter->findvalue('content');
  push @{ $filters{$type} }, $content;
}

my $log = $parser->load_xml(location => 'log.xml');

for my $message ( $log->findnodes('/log/message') ) {
  my $type = $message->findvalue('type');
  my $content = $message->findvalue('content');
  unless ( any { $content =~ /\Q$_/i } @{ $filters{$type} } ) {
    $message->parentNode->removeChild($message);
  }
}

print $log->toString(1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
  <message>
    <type>warning</type>
    <from>cody</from>
    <content>my head hurts really bad right now</content>
  </message>
</log>
```